# Typing in destructured property in typescript

Tags: typescript

I have a following interface

```
export interface Row {
    userId: number | number[];
    category: string;
    type: string;
}
```

Now at some point I am destructuring this object

```
const { userId } = row
```

When I try to use for example `userId.length` it complains as Typescript is not sure that it is an array of numbers.

Is there any way I can tell typescript that I am sure its an array.

I have tried `const {userId}: {userId: number[]} = row` but it is still complaining.

Thanks

Comment: "*When I try to use for example `userId.length` it complains as Typescript is not sure that it is an array of numbers.*" but...it's not an array of numbers. It might also be a number, as per the type you've given it. A number doesn't have a `length` property. Not sure why you expect TS to know the exact type the variable would have, when the type is not specific enough.

Comment: `(userId as number[]).length`? But that might be undefined, per your own types. Look into type guards, you could *check* whether it has a length and narrow the type that way: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#type-guards-and-differentiating-types

Comment: That is on purpose `userId: number | number[]` because I am getting this object from another source and they could send a number or array of numbers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your `userId` maybe is a `number` or a number array

```
userId: number | number[];
```

If you make sure that it always is a number array, just change your `userId` type to `userId:number[];` instead of `userId: number | number[];`

Or not, just confirm that `userId` is a number array, before you want to working with a number array:

```
const { userId } = row;

if (Array.isArray(userId)) {
  // You can use userId as a number array in this scope
  console.log(userId.length); //
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another solution that will also be supported by typescript:

```
const { userId } = row;
const userIdLength = Array.isArray(userId) ? userId.length : 0;
```

Comment: I don't know if `0` is a useful default, how would you distinguish between a single `number` and an empty `number[]`?

Comment: That depends on the implementation, but this code ensures compilation and linting :)